# vuetify parallax fluid template issue

Tags: css, vue.js, parallax, vuetify.js

I am trying to setup a fluid template to be used in responsive design viewports. 
On medium viewports ( md ) the display is fine . ... see [codepen](https://codepen.io/erwin16/pen/QxmrvK)
the 3 v-card ( rounded) are in a row... ( parallax background image height is 380px)

however it does not scale right on smaller viewports ( sm or xs )
all v-catds are not displayed, because the height of the parallax background image is not adjusted ( it's still 380px height)

how can I set it up right , in order to get in smaller viewports all my v-cards in column

**HTML**

```
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-parallax src="https://vuetifyjs.com/static/doc-images/parallax/material2.jpg" height="380">
          <v-layout row wrap align-center justify-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm12 md3>
                <v-card class="elevation-0 rounded-card">
                  <v-card-title primary-title class="layout justify-center">
                    <h1>TITLE 1</h1>
                    </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-text>
                    ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque cursus enim et justo eleifend pharetra. Nam consectetur, nulla in viverra mattis, ipsum libero faucibus odio, at eleifend mauris arcu non nibh. Aliquam congue augue sed sapien tristique, eget faucibus risus pulvinar. Nullam ut nunc felis.
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
             </v-flex>
             <v-flex xs12 sm12 md3 offset-md1>
                <v-card class="elevation-0 rounded-card">
                  <v-card-title primary-title class="layout justify-center">
                    <h1>TITLE 2</h1>
                    </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-text>Proin felis diam, placerat ut lacinia viverra, dapibus ut sapien. Curabitur non dolor sed tortor aliquet lacinia. Maecenas ut porta velit, vel elementum sem. Quisque tincidunt vel nisl quis dignissim. Suspendisse accumsan leo sed neque sodales, in congue metus egestas. Maecenas molestie, eros.
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
             </v-flex>
                     <v-flex xs12 sm12 md3 offset-md1>
                <v-card class="elevation-0 rounded-card">
                  <v-card-title primary-title class="layout justify-center">
                    <h1>TITLE 3</h1>
                    </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-text>
                    Quisque non felis massa. Suspendisse vel aliquam orci, eget aliquet est. In efficitur nisi vel massa volutpat, vitae varius velit volutpat. Duis non maximus nunc, ut tincidunt eros. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum libero justo, euismod et massa finibus, tincidunt euismod libero.
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
             </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-parallax>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .rounded-card {
      border-radius: 50px;
    }
    .card__text {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 3em;
    }
```

**JS**

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',

    })
```

Comment: Well you can set conditional on `v-layout` to be a column I guess `<v-layout :column="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown">`

Comment: thanks for your feedback ... I just found a solution , setting v-parallax height to 100% and the .parallax CSS min-height to 380px ... updated my codepen ..

Comment: I think you shouldn't edit question (or codepen in the question) with a working example (e.g. answer) while removing original non-working example because future readers wont see where the problem was in the first place. So IMO you should leave non-working example in the question, and post a solution as an answer. So just fork codepen and then edit.

Comment: done... I updated the codepen url to the initial error state

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED

setting the v-parallax height to 100%

```
<v-parallax src="https://vuetifyjs.com/static/doc-images/parallax/material2.jpg" height="100%">
```

and adding into the CSS

```
.parallax {
   min-height: 380px;
}
```

Comment: height="100%" does not work because the height prop only accept number(not %) and in this will it will ignore the height you give and will set the height to 500px that is the default height for the parallax